# Sweave's "fig=TRUE" cannot write file

Tags: r, sweave

I use `Sweave` to get my `R` data into `LaTeX`.
While this works fine with "just data", I am not able to include plots.

My `.Rnw`-file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Example}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Go}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE, include=TRUE,  eps = FALSE>>= 
boxplot(na.omit(mydata$age))
@ 
\end{center}
\caption{Boxplot ``myplot''}
\label{fig:liability}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

While Sweave runs through this without any error message, no plot-file is written. Thus, compiling the `.tex`-file gives an "file not found"-error at the `includegraphics`-command.

I changed the code into something like this, in order to create a `jpg`-file:

```
<<Mytest,echo=FALSE>>=                 
jpeg(filename = "NW-liability.jpg", width = 480, height = 480, pointsize = 12, bg = "white")
boxplot(na.omit(mydata$age))
dev.off()
@ 
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{NW-liability.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption{Boxplot ``myplot''}
\label{fig:liability}
\end{figure}
```

and this works (so permissions seem to be OK).

Is there any other thing I have to configure in order to use Sweave's `fig=TRUE`-option?

(My system is Archlinux)

Comment: Where do you define or read `mydata`?

Comment: I load it in a previor chunk... try to replace my code with `plot(iris)` ... It still wont work here..

Comment: When I Sweave your document with `boxplot(na.omit(iris))`, I do not get any error.

Comment: I dont get any error, too... the problem is, that I dont get any graphic-files (pdf, eps, jpg, png) of that boxplot either....